# Loading search results in a new form

Tags: c#, forms, search

I have been working on trying to understand `ArrayList` but I have run into a problem with the final part of my search function.

I have an array list set up to take data in from a `StreamReader`.  The data consists of numerous properties to do with teams, such as their name and the image path to their logo.

I have then created a search that scans through the array list for a specific piece of string input through a textbox by the user.

I have then created an if statement to open up a new form if that search was returned true.

I would like the new form to load up each property of the team according to the data searched for. E.g if I searched for "Liverpool" it would then come up with the manager name, stadium name as well as the searched for name in the new form.  I do not know how to do this.

The only tool that I can really think of to do this is the `load.event` procedure but I can not find a lot of information about linking it to an array list.

```
 private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Object obj in allTeams)
        {
            Team = (Team)obj;
            if (team.teamName.ToUpper() == nameToMatch.ToUpper()) //case insensitive search.
            {
                FormTeam frmTeam = new FormTeam(Team); //windows form that displays team info.
                frmTeam.Visible = true;
                break; 
            }
        }

    }
```

above is my search function. (I have not used `List<T>` because it was required that everything must be stored in an `ArrayList`.)

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? And if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, you may want to use Linq on your ArrayList

```
foreach(var team in allTeams.OfType<Team>())
{
    if(team.TeamName.Equals(nameToMatch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    { 
      frmTeam = new FormTeam(Team); 
      Aplication.Run(frmTeam); // or frmTeam.Show();
      break;
    }
}
```

Inside the Constructor of your TeamForm class you simply assign all Values from the Team- Object to the fields on the Form.

```
public FormTeam (Team team)
{
    teamName.Text = team.TeamName;   // label or something
    teamPlayerCount.text = team.PlayerCount.ToString();
    ...

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am still trying to get my head around this. I didn't use LINQ as I am not that confident in c# yet. The method you have demonstrated in part 1. Will that not just show the team name only? I kind of wanted to show each attribute of the team (manager, stadium) from just one search value.

Comment: Yea you have to implement all you need, I saw to late that your constructor accepts the whole teamobject. i will fix this.

Comment: This is still quite confusing to me. To clarify part 1 signify's to return the search result and if true launch the new form. The code on the 2nd part then is set placed as the first method for the new created form. Since the constructor accepts the entire object I then assign each value e.g ` teamName.Text = team.TeamName;` to something like a textbox or label right? Sorry for being such a pain by the way I know this must seem tedious.

Comment: I removed the any-part to reduce the confusion here. 
as for the last part you are right. Assign all values from the Teamobject you want to display, to members of the form. Like a laber or a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search on a string such as the teamName, it would be better to use something like a `Dictionary<string,Team>` rather than an `Arraylist`.  Then you'd be able to do

```
Team t = dic[nameToMatch.ToUpper()];
```

where dic is the instance of `Dictionary<string,Team>` that contains all your teams.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing a variable name there.  I think you meant

```
foreach (Object obj in allTeams)
    {
        Team t = (Team)obj;
        if (t.teamName.ToUpper() == nameToMatch.ToUpper()) //case insensitive search.
        {
            FormTeam frmTeam = new FormTeam(t); //windows form that displays team info.
            frmTeam.Visible = true;
            break; 
        }
    }
```

But why not used a typed generic List, not have to do all this silly casting.

But your question is "how can I pass what I searched to the new form", correct?  I'd change the constructor for FormTeam to something like `FormTeam(Team t, string nameToMatch)` and save the value locally in TeamForm so you can do highlighting or whatever.